# How to get Configuration from appsettings in .NET Core console application

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application

I am using a .NET Core 7 worker project in which I want to add app settings to my `program.cs` class, but for that I need an `IConfiguration` interface from the host context.

How can I get and inject it as a singleton in the project?

Here is my code:

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        // Here I want to add a configuration from appsettings.json and then map it to my Configuration class
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

Here is my `appsettings.json`:

```
{
    "ServiceName": "Test service",
    "connectionString": ""
}
```

```
public class Configuration
{
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Taken a look [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47821334/7450780)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Bind method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#bind-hierarchical-configuration-data-using-the-options-pattern) to bind the Configuration segment to a static typed object instance.

`Configuration.GetSection(PositionOptions.Position).Bind(positionOptions);`

Or even more convenient the `Get` method

```
 Configuration.GetSection(PositionOptions.Position).Get<PositionOptions>()
```